# Python- selenium webdriver is not able to find these buttons on modal window

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

[Not able to click x or continue to flights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiFIa.png)

Here is the url: https://www.kayak.com/flights/ORD-JFK/2020-09-13/2020-09-20?sort=bestflight_a
using css = '.Button-No-Standard-Style.close-button'
I was using the following to find and click it:
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.Button-No-Standard-Style.close-button').click()

Answer (score 0):

What I found out was the button had dynamic ID. I had to click the button based on partial ID comparison.
I used:
cl_bt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'covid-loading-dialog-close')]")
where 'covid-loading-dialog-close' was the part of the ID that was not changing.